# Idiom for meeting one's match

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms

I'm translating a comic book, and I got stumped on a certain idiom, not sure what I could use in its place in the English translation.

The Polish "Trafiła kosa na kamień" (lit: the scythe hit a rock) is an expression of shadenfreude, when someone (possibly disliked) who'd successfully, even effortlessly conquer all problems so far, meets an obstacle or opponent they are unable to overcome.

Is there an English idiom or a common expression that matches such usage?

Comment: You could metaphorically ***run into, hit,*** or ***come up against a brick wall***.

Comment: How about **_met/faced his nemesis_**? , _**Got a thorn in his flesh_** ? or maybe **_found a fly in the ointment_**?

Comment: But ***meeting one's match*** [**is**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meet%20one%27s%20match) an idiom. So, you've already got your answer. If not, are you simply asking for *another* idiom that means the same thing? (If so, what's wrong with the first one?)

Comment: "Met his Waterloo"?  It implies a series of wins until meeting a more powerful opponent or greater challenge.

Comment: Perhaps: "He got his comeuppance."

Comment: @tmgr: that one seems to fit quite nice.

Comment: *He got what was coming to him* could be a more vernacular form of *comeuppance*.